# Unable to ignore optional query param when making a request

Tags: java, spring

I am making a Rest service call using Spring. The rest call works fine if I pass in all the params or if I pass in empty string for the params. But if I intentionally not pass anything for the param, it throws following exception. Note that query params are all optional.

**IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for someField".**

In following example, I don't want to pass anything for some_field field. But it doesn't work unless I pass in an empty string. as mentioned.

In my config file:

```
url=https://mydomain/locale/type/{type}/id/{id}?some_field={someField}&my_point={myPoint}
```

Method to make the rest call.

```
public Object getDetails(String url) {

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id", id);
        params.put("my_point", myPoint);
//        params.put("some_field", ""); // Works if I add this. 
        params.put("type", someType);

        return template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, responseType, params);
    }
```

Comment: Its validated at api side it seems

Comment: If you have a parameter in your URL template you must supply a substitution for it, else it will simply fail. If it is optional then don't put it in the template, but dynamically build the template.

Comment: It seams that you are calling it using Spring Template.  In case of spring Template you need to pass all the param.  If you don't want to pass than you need to set null for that field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try surrounding it with an if block that checks if your param is null. If it is, execute the code to make it work, or if it has something, put it in the params as always.

```
if(some_field == null){
    params.put("some_field", "");
} else {
    //your expected execution when that some_field contains something goes here
}
```